# os dev : vga printing strings and strange compiler behavior

Tags: c++, string, optimization, kernel, vga

I am trying to implement a very simple function for printing strings in my kernel.

The trouble seems very weird to me and i'm thinking that i might have missed something important, but i have no idea what.

So, i have a code that doesn't work:

```
void print (char c) {
    static unsigned i =0;
    if (c == '\n')
        i += 80 - i % 80;
    else {
        *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(0xb8000) + i) 
             = static_cast<uint16_t>(c) | 0x0f << 8;
        ++i;
    }
}
void print (const char* txt) {
    for (int i=0; txt[i]!=0; ++i)
        print(txt[i]);
}
```

Please look at the 3rd line in this extract : if (c=='\n')
What if i change it to an innocent : if (false)
Then **it magically works perfectly**... it doesn't work with if(c=='T') or anything else either, anyway there is no '\n' yet in my test code :

```
print("test");
```

I wondered if, for any obscure reason, the

```
i += 80 - i % 80;
```

part was making troubles, but it works no better if i change it by a semicolon...

But that's not all. I'm compiling with these flags:

```
 clang++ -target i386 -std=c++11 -O2 -fno-builtin -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
```

If i remove the the optimization flag '-O2', then it never works in any case.

I don't understand what i miss...
PLEASE, can you help me ? I'm turning crazy :P

=============EDIT=============

after investigations, it seems mtrrs are not supported with default qemu settings (i checked this using a specific cpu setting). Check code here:
(worth noting that osdev says checking bit 5 while intel says bit 12, and this latter seems to work under qemu)

```
bool msr () {
    uint32_t eax, edx;
    cpu::cpuid(0x01, eax, edx);
    return edx & (1<<12);
}
```

Here's my current codebase.

```
void print (char c) {
    static unsigned i =0;
    if (c == '\n')
        i += 80 - i % 80;
    else {
        volatile const auto b = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(0xb8000);
        b[i++] = static_cast<uint16_t>(c) | 0x0f << 8;
    }
}
void print (const char* txt) {
    for (int i=0; txt[i]!=0; ++i)
        print(txt[i]);
}

//==============================================================================
// kmain
//==============================================================================
[[noreturn]] extern "C" void kmain () {

    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "mov    %%cr0, %%eax            \n"
            "or     $(1<<30), %%eax         \n"
            "mov    %%eax, %%cr0            \n"
            "wbinvd                         \n"
            :
            :
            : "eax");
    print("text text text");

    for (;;);
}
```

the asm part here is to set the bit 30 in cr0, which intel claims is to disable caching.
This still prints the first letter while a shorter string is printed fine...

I don't know what to search about now. Do you have any idea ? Thank you alot

=============EDIT=============

Wow, just found the nice bug...

The solution was in the linker script:

```
.rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K) {
    *(.rodata)
}
```

became:

```
.rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K) {
    *(.rodata*)
}
```

just because clang generated me not a *.rodata* section, but instead a *.rodata.str1.1* one.
This was causing an absence of the rodata string unless it was as short as 4 chars, in which case it would turn out to be represented as an int... with -O2.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Have you looked at the assembler output? Have you set up MTRRs to make the VGA buffer uncached?

Comment: ya, sorry: "doesn't work" means that there's nothing printed on screen.

Comment: I didn't know what it was and i'm currently searching for documentation about it... (if you have some reference, i would love) I also wondered if a volatile keyword on the vga memory pointer was relevant in this situation ? Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: If compiler options are making a difference, then it's almost certainly not a MTRR (Memory Type Range Registers) problem, but an issue with the way that your code works. I would use `volatile` to ensure the memory store is always done. Compiler may be confused about what you are storing, and think that it's not needed.

Comment: [Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3: System Programming](https://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/5061-102-1-8118/Pentium_SW_Developers_Manual_Vol3_SystemProgramming.pdf). I'm not sure this is your problem though. Try volatile too, it might help.

Comment: Thank you both. My code now uses a volatile pointer on 0xb8000 to write chars. it seems to have changed the behaviour, now it works sometimes. I would not be confused if MTRR were involved here afai understand, since there is a difference between a short and a wider string passed to "print" : the wider one leads to only the first char to be printed out... does it seem to be a caching problem you think ? I'm learning about mtrr (msr ?) anyway since it looks quite interesting to deal with.

Comment: If behavior is not determenistic, and longer strings are more likely to fail, I'm guessing it's an interrupt problem. Perhaps some interrupt handler doesn't restore some register or flag properly?

Comment: I don't have any interrupt stuff yet, but "cli" is on my bootstrap before entering C++ code.

Comment: (note: see the edit of the question)